# css url function not working within theme provider breakpoints

Tags: html, css, jsx

The `background: url(${(props) => props.imageUrl}) center center;` is not working within the media queries but is working at the top (mobile) level. I know the media queries are working because when the `background-color: red;` is showing up in desktop view.

imageUrl and mobileImageUrl are both correctly being passed in. I tested by putting either at the mobile level.

```
export const Wrapper = styled.div<StyledWrapperProps>`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  background: url(${(props) => props.mobileImageUrl}) center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
  background-color: blue;

  margin-top: -28px;
  ${({ theme: { breakpoints } }) => `
    ${breakpoints.tablet} {
      background: url(${(props) => props.imageUrl}) center center;
      margin-top: -32px;
      background-color: orange;
    };
    ${breakpoints.laptop} {
      background: url(${(props) => props.imageUrl}) center center;
      margin-top: -36px;
      background-color: red;
    };
  `}
`;
```

I am currently working around this by adding

```
    @media (min-width: 600px) {
    background: url(${(props) => props.imageUrl}) center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
  }
```